# MapView hiding "Allow location services" prompt

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, mapkit

The first screen of my app is a MapView so when the user opens it up for the first time it prompts for Location Services. The issue is that immediately after the prompt comes up asking for location access it gets hidden (fades into the background) like some subview came over top of it.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are either proceeding with another prompt for location services before the confirmation is given, or else you are on iOS 8 and prompting for location services (which is now asynchronous) and then going ahead and using them before this can complete.

Comment: Ahh I didn't know the prompt was no asynchronous, thanks! Would you know of a way to add a callback to the confirmation?

Comment: Just tried it with every map view delegate method, every single one of them hides it.